# Name of output node tensorflow checkpoint

Tags: tensorflow

I have some tensorflow checkpoint files. Now, I am trying to freeze the model and create a .pb file. For this, I need the output node name. I got a list of node names, but I am unable to figure out the output node name. From the network architecture, I found that the model has a fully connected layer at its output. My variable list has the following names (it is a very long list, so I am keeping here only those related to the FC layer),

```
('fully_connected/biases', [2]),  
('fully_connected/biases/Adam', [2]),  
('fully_connected/biases/Adam_1', [2]),  
('fully_connected/weights', [256, 2]),  
('fully_connected/weights/Adam', [256, 2]),  
('fully_connected/weights/Adam_1', [256, 2])
```

From this, what exactly is the name that I should specify in the function 'tf.freeze_graph'?

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, it should be the latest node in the list. In this case it should be `/biases`, but I'm not sure about adam's internal variables. Maybe you could try it and test?

Comment: I tried giving 'fully_connected/biases' and 'fully_connected/weights', but when I reloaded the saved .pb file in a new graph and printed the node names, only 'prefix/fully_connected/weights' and 'prefix/fully_connected/biases' came. It was supposed to print all node names starting from input as I could understand from https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc

Comment: I did tensorboard visualization and added few more node names. Now I can see all the node names. The model is complicated and it concatenates multiple sub models. I gave the output node names of those sub models as well.